# How to define a code text for a predefined result?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-drive

I couldn't word it very well in my question but a detailed explanation will be easier to understand.

I want to define a code -such as "A"- and a result text for that code or in my case I need a date. What I am basically asking is that on a specific column whenever I write "A" and press enter, the corresponding date should fill the cell. I didn't know how to search this so I had to create this question. Preferably, the code and the corresponding text should be on a different worksheet.

I need it on Google Drive, but if not I am okay with an Excel answer as well.

Comment: In excel you could do this with a `Worksheet_Change` macro.  So, for Excel, you could research that or event-triggered macros.

Comment: In Google Sheets the function similar to `Worksheet_Change` is `onEdit(e)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely new do Google Apps Script and JavaScript, but this seems to work:

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function onEdit(e) {
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var target_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A1:B10");
  if (activeSheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      var currentValue = target_range.getCell(i,1).getValue();
      var currentDate = target_range.getCell(i,2).getValue();
      if (currentValue == e.value) {
        range.setValue(currentDate);
        break;
        }
      }
  }
}
```

**How it looks in action:**

[image: In action]

On Excel VBA, it would look something like:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Set r = Sheets(2).Range("A1:A10")   'This is where I have the "code", with the date in column "B"
If Target.Count = 1 Then
    Set c = r.Find(Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then Target.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
End If
End Sub
```

Both of these will search the second sheet in the `A1-A10` range for the entered value in sheet 1. And then return the date (or whatever) from column `B` on the corresponding row.